# Counting lost packets with perl

Tags: perl, counter, packet

I'm writing a small script that returns the pingtimes for a given host. So far everything is working as it should but would want to be able to see how many packets that are lost.

When you run the standard ping command in a windows command prompt you get something like this:

```
Ping-statistic for 173.194.70.138:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0%)
```

How can I make perl count everytime a packet is lost? Is there a way to invoke windows commands within perl?

My current code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Time::HiRes;
use Net::Ping;

use vars qw($ARGV $ret $duration $ip);

my $host    = $ARGV[0] or print "Usage is: $0 host [timeout]\n" and exit 1;
my $timeout = $ARGV[1] || 5;
my $p  = Net::Ping->new('icmp', $timeout);

if ($p->ping($host)) {
    $p->hires();{
($ret, $duration, $ip) = $p->ping($host);
    printf("$host [ip: $ip] is online (packet return time: %.2f ms)\n", 1000*$duration);
  }  

$p->close();  

}else{
     print "No such host, timeout of $timeout seconds reached\n";
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the hostname cannot be found or there is a problem with the IP number, the success flag returned will be undef. Otherwise, the success flag will be 1 if the host is reachable and 0 if it is not.

so `$p->ping` can return `undef`, `1`, or `0`

```
my $lost = 0;
my $n = 10;
while ($n--) {
  # die if ping returns undef
  my $ok = $p->ping($host) // die "No such host, timeout of $timeout seconds reached\n";
  $lost++ if !$ok;
}
print "$lost lost packets\n";
```